# Why new serverless framework stops seeing variables?

Tags: serverless-framework

I have working AWS application which builds via serverless framework. In serverless.yml are a lot of variables. One sample:

```
custom:
  config: ${file(env/${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.region}.yml)}
```

when I had run **sls deploy --stage mystage --region us-east-1**, it perfectly worked and the framework found proper file (mystage-us-east-1.yml) in env directory.

But after upgrade Framework Core to 3.33.0 version it stoped working. Now I after same command I have an error:

```
Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "custom.config": Value not found at "self" source,
```

Why new version framework doesn't work with variables like did it before?

Comment: Can we see the area of your `serverless.yaml` that references `${self:custom:config}` ?